# "Plausible" vs. "possible"

Tags: differences, adjectives, connotation

I am looking to find the difference between *possible* and *plausible*.

Here is what Apple's dictionary gives for each word:

> Possible: Able to be done; within the power or capacity of someone or something
>
> Plausible: (of an argument or statement) seeming reasonable or probable

I mean, other than these definitions, are there any connotative differences?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can define something *possible* in mathematical terms as having a non-zero probability of being true.

As for *plausible*, the concept does not draw on mathematics but rather on mere common sense.  The etymology is the same as *applause*.  Something  is *plausible* if it's acceptable (loosely: if it deserves applause).  That is to say if its probability is reasonable.

If you add *probable* and *likely* in the equation, you can order theses adjectives by ascending probability as follows:

*possible* => *plausible* => *probable* = *likely*.

Answer (score 18):

I think the easiest way to think about the difference is this: if something is possible it  might be true; if it is plausible it *sounds like* it might be true.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't attach any kind of probability to *plausible*: to me it is something (or someone) which is not obviously wrong.  A successful con artist will usually be plausible.

Answer (score 6):

To me, *plausible* is something that is explainable, while things that are *possible* but implausible would surprise me.

I wouldn't be surprised if a plausible event occurred, but I could take notice if a possible event happened that was implausible because it was caused by an absurd chain of events.

(Your mileage may vary on the threshold level of reason or probability that goes into either word. For example, my physics friends could say that due to quantum weirdness, anything is possible – it just may take trillions of years before you'd expect to see it happen. But most people would object to this and argue that the scope of *possible* should be limited to Newtonian physics.)

Answer (score 6):

*Plausible* is referred to an explanation, an argument, or a statement, while *possible* is referred to a fact, or an event.

For example, my explanation on how in future time traveling will be possible could be plausible, but that doesn't mean traveling through time will be possible.