# What is the difference between "impossible" and "implausible"?

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Plausible” vs. “possible”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27720/plausible-vs-possible)

My English-Russian dictionary translates "impossible" and "implausible" absolutely the same. But there must be a difference. Could you explain, please?

Comment: Somewhat sheepishly, I'm voting to reopen. Per comments under @Carlo's answer, there's certainly scope for disagreement about what exactly *totally implausible* means. There's no doubt in my mind that the negating **im-** prefix is doing something subtly different when applied to “plausible” vs. “possible”. Even if not everyone (or perhaps *no-one*) agrees with me on that point, the fact that ***I*** think it is my justification for the reopen vote.

Answer (score 4):

No, these words are very different in meanings.

"Implausible" means "not seeming reasonable or probable", while "impossible" means "not able to occur, exist or be done," as you read in Oxford Dictionary of English.

Probably, in some contexts, "totally implausible" could mean "impossible."

You can use these words together. For example:

> - It is the macroevolutionary ideas, new species evolving from a variety
>     of species, that remains a mystery, and for most considered
>     implausible and impossible. ([See](http://books.google.com/books?id=QVmCHST3YhkC&pg=PA187&lpg=PA187&dq=%22implausible+and+impossible%22&source=bl&ots=RY4_6iY_KT&sig=uNuTpr8Z30OpGYFzY3xUWAPU3Gs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=haXVUPaiNOqm4ASEyIDgDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22implausible%20and%20impossible%22&f=false).)
> - But considering that the Broncos won seven of their games this season
>     by a total of 25 points and lost four by 105, victory over the
>     Steelers will be mission implausible, but not impossible. ([See](http://www.denverpost.com/paige/ci_19698016).)

I hope the above explanation clarify your doubts.

Comment: Not sure I agree that *totally implausible* could mean *impossible*. Why does the addition of the adverb change the meaning of implausible to impossible? I think that's confusing not clarifying.

Comment: @spiceyokooko  I think you're right. In Carlo_R's defense, *implausible* is often **used** thus, as if *implausible* and *improbable* were synonyms; and what is "totally improbable" is, by definition, impossible. But I think this is a misuse: "not *seeming* probable" is not the same thing as "not probable". *Plausible* speaks to perception, *probable* to fact.

Comment: @StoneyB But it doesn't help clarify the difference between the two words was the point I was trying to make.

Comment: @spiceyokooko  Exactly, which is what I was agreeing with and trying to counter-clarify. Perhaps I said too much (*thunderous offstage applause*).

Comment: @StoneyB You can never say too much. I admire your writing on here it's beautifully crafted.

Comment: @spiceyokooko  (*wiping away a tear*) What I love about this place is that it offers an opportunity to write well.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: I think Carlo is quite right that *totally implausible* can (and indeed usually *does*) mean exactly the same as *impossible* (i.e. - *not feasible under **any** circumstances*). Different speakers will obviously make their own distinctions on such fine points (which cannot possibly be established definitively using dictionaries or other "authoritative" sources), but I personally would say that whereas there's a vanishingly small possibility of something *totally improbable* happening, if it's *totally implausible* there's absolutely no chance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid I don't agree and for once I'm going to put my virtual foot down and say that if you wish to imply something is not possible, you would not be using the word implausible - with or without supporting adverbs - it's poor use of the English language. Given that this site is about the correct use of it, I find it a poor example.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: As I said, there cannot be a *definitive* position on this one (well, that's what I think, although obviously you disagree! :) Words mean what speakers *think* they mean, and no amount of virtual foot-stamping by others who think differently is likely to change that. I'm not saying I totally endorse Humpty Dumpty's position, but I think you have to admit he's got a point.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Totally implausible = totally unworthy of applause. How about a slow hand clap instead?

Comment: haha - a slow hand clap for *my* position, or for *yours?* Or should we just get on with clapping in unison as a prelude to singing from the same hymn sheet? You start the rhythm with a good old foot-stomp, and we'll take it from the top!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's the trouble with words, you never know whose mouth they've been in :)

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Well, as you'll know, Carlo has posted the actual question, so let the shootout begin! (But I'll be shooting from the fingertip/hip, not the mouth or lip :)

Answer (score 2):

Words rarely translate accurately, which is why it is a good idea to use single language dictionaries if you can. From OED.

*implausible, adj.*

*Pronunciation:  /ɪmˈplɔːzɪb(ə)l/*

*†1. Not worthy of applause; personally unacceptable. Obs.*

*2. Not having the appearance of truth, probability, or acceptability; not plausible.*

I think meaning (1), though obsolete, neatly summarises the concept of *implausible*. Contrast with *impossible*

*impossible, adj. and n.*

*Pronunciation:  /ɪmˈpɒsɪb(ə)l/*

*a. Not possible; that cannot be done or effected; that cannot exist or come into being; that cannot be, in existing or specified circumstances. Const. to or for.*

Comment: +1 The *good idea ... dictionaries* bit needs to be in 40-point bold.