# Could "totally implausible" mean "impossible"?

Tags: meaning

The question "What is the difference between 'impossible' and 'implausible'?" has generated an interesting discussion on the differences, if any, between "totally implausible" and "impossible".

More precisely, the debate arose from the following statement:

> Probably, in some contexts, "totally implausible" could mean
>   "impossible."

Since it seems that there is controversy on this matter, as the following comments show,

- "there's certainly scope for disagreement about what exactly totally implausible means. There's no doubt in my mind that the negating im- prefix is doing something subtly different when applied to “plausible” vs. “possible”. Even if not everyone (or perhaps no-one) agrees with me on that point."
- "implausible is often used thus, as if implausible and improbable were synonyms; and what is "totally improbable" is, by definition, impossible. But I think this is a misuse: "not seeming probable" is not the same thing as "not probable". Plausible speaks to perception, probable to fact."
- "Not sure I agree that totally implausible could mean impossible. Why does the addition of the adverb change the meaning of implausible to impossible?"

I wonder: could "totally implausible" mean "impossible?"

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Plausible" vs. "possible"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27720/plausible-vs-possible)

Comment: @Robusto: I think the specific issue of *negation* here makes this one a distinct question. You may take the view that *plausible/implausible* are interrelated in exactly the same way as *possible/impossible*, but that ain't necessarily so, and I think the complexities are even greater when coupled to an "absolute" modifier like *totally*. I don't say a single question/answer pair *couldn't* cover everything, but it certainly seems to me neither page currently achieves this.

Comment: It could be used, but that would not be an accurate usage of plausible or possible. 'Totally implausible' = no one in their right mind would expect that to happen; 'impossible' = not possible at all (belief isn't part of it).

Comment: @Mitch: Except that from any plausible epistemological stance, *impossible* can only mean ***believed** not to be possible*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: lots of things are impossible well outside of belief such as logical or physical impossibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take Barrie's point that *plausibility* is primarily concerned with appearance rather than actuality. But I think there's a limit to how far one can take such strictly literal interpretations.

In most contexts, *probable/possible* mean *likely/unlikely*, but whereas the corresponding negated form *improbable* means ***not*** likely, *impossible* doesn't mean *not unlikely* - it means *definitely not*.

By the same token, *convincing/plausible* usually mean *very believable/just about believable*. I'm aware some people use *plausible* to mean *convincing*, but I think most people need something *very/totally plausible* to actually be convinced.

As John Lawler [often reminds us](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59628/2637), *negatives [are] probably the most complex portion of English semantics and the weirdest part of its syntax*.

And as Cerberus [points out here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/21852/2637), *[probability] is a complicated issue [in the context of linguistics]*.

---

In *my* version of English, if something is *implausible*, it's *unlikely, but at least feasible*. But if it's ***totally*** implausible, it has no element of plausibility/feasibility whatsoever, and I personally do not distinguish that from *impossible*.

Comment: Erm, how does possible imply unlikely? From OED - Possible, that is capable of being; that may or can exist, be done, or happen. Impossible - not possible; that cannot be done or effected; that cannot exist or come into being; that cannot be. I beleive you're stretching the realms of plausibility!

Comment: Erm, I mean *in contexts where the speaker might use either or both word*. For example, I think it's probable that I'm right, but I admit it's possible that you are. That leaves no doubt which of the two I consider most likely, and the opposite meaning would definitely apply if I were to reverse those two words. Stop being so literal-minded!

Comment: Well, does totally possible change the meaning of possible? Does totally impossible change the meaning of impossible? Aka, does totally plausible change the meaning of plausible? Yet you're suggesting that totally implausible changes the meaning to not possible? It's not logical said Dr Spock.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: This isn't going anywhere. You're determined to stick to strict literal/logical interpretations, and to ignore my points that (1) language isn't necessarily logical; (2) particularly not when it comes to negation; (3) *even more particularly* not when concepts involving probability and/or desirability are involved. I can easily cite you examples where *totally implausible* means *impossible*, and my point is not diminished by the possibility that you might feasibly find examples where it means *possible, but not at all credible*.

Comment: And you're missing my point of why you would want to use *totally implausible* when impossible would be a better word that means the same thing? Why use two words when you can use one?

Comment: Besides, the word "totally", in light of its current over-use as an emotionally driven intensifier instead of merely an adverb, may not be meant to take "implausable" to the highest degree of impossibility.

Answer (score 6):

Plausibility is concerned with appearance rather than truth. If something is implausible, whether totally so or not, then it doesn’t sound convincing, it doesn’t sound as if it’s possible. To say something is impossible, on the other hand, is to say that it really cannot be done, not just that it seems that it cannot be done.

Comment: I agree. I don't see how the addition of an adverb to *implausible* substantially changes the meaning from *unlikely* to *impossible*.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Of course adverbs can radically change meanings. Would you rather be *dead, totally dead*, or just *somewhat dead?*. In most contexts, your chances of surviving either of the first two are non-existent, so arguably *totally* there is meaningless. But with *somewhat*, it's practically a dead cert that you're still alive.

Comment: I don't think this invalidates the quotation. To extend Fumblefingers' example, "In some contexts *cut in half could mean* (or at least include) *'dead'*", though *dead* certainly does not mean *cut in half*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not saying the addition of an adverb cannot change meanings, I'm saying that in that instance it doesn't change the meaning.

Comment: @spiceyokooko: Well, we *know* you think *in this instance it doesn't change meaning*, since you've effectively said several times that you don't believe *implausibility* can be so extreme as to deny *possibility*. But I see no reason to suppose *implausible* is unusual in the sense of *not* being capable of adverbial modification. And per my own answer, I see two very good reasons for supposing that idiomatically, it's a far more "malleable" word than most.

Comment: @FumbleFingers There's a reason the English language contains so many words - it's a very precise language. There's also a reason for the existence of two words (implausible and impossible) that have distinct differences in their meaning. IMHO, it's poor and incorrect use of the language to change the meaning of one of those words with the additional of another to mean the same as one word without substantially altering the meaning. After all, this SE is about the *correct use* of the language.

Comment: If everyone took your position, languages would never change to any significant degree (you'd just get the occasional new word, when we invented something that didn't previously exist). In practice, SE (and the study of language in general) is more about ***actual*** use of language, not *correct* use as defined by those people who decry its "misuse".

Comment: @FumbleFingers  The question is Where do you draw the line? --because there must be a line or language is (literally) impossible. For instance: I intensely dislike the contemporary trend toward redefining *reticent* as *reluctant*, not least because it takes a fine chisel out of my toolbox and turns it into a second-rate screwdriver. Am I to follow the trend, or resist it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: ELU is not about both?

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, if someone said he was *reticent to **say** something*, I wouldn't really be bothered. But if someone was *reticent to **go** somewhere* I might be minded to pick him up on it. But regardless of such "someones", you can keep *your* copy of the word in a separate compartment from *reluctant* in *your* toolbox. Nobody forces you to use words in a way you're not comfortable with - besides, for a stickler like you, wouldn't it be totally implausible for you to actually *say* *"**I am reticent!**"* ?! :)

Comment: ... but still possible

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Gresham's law: bad usage drives out good.

Comment: @StoneyB. What is _bad usage_? It is language that fails to do what its originator intended it to do.

Comment: @BarrieEngland  Indeed - or achieves something which its originator did not intend. When someone writes me "I'm reticent to push forward with this" I may understand perfectly well what he means; but I also understand him to be a slovenly or inadequately educated writer.

Comment: @StoneyB. Yes, language conveys more than meaning.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  No one would accuse me of **taciturnity**; I am on the contrary **loquacious** and **outspoken**; but I am **reluctant** to speak of some matters and observe a seemly **reticence** concerning them.

Comment: @StoneyB.: By implication from Barrie's point, arguably the fact that someone could *say* "I'm reticent to push forward" actually suggests they're ***enriching*** language. Not only do we understand exactly what they *meant* to say - we also pick up supplementary information about their command of English (not to mention possible clues as to where they were drug up, if they speak with a pronounced accent! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  [That's glory for you!](http://sabian.org/looking_glass6.php)