# Is there a one-word opposite of implausible?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

If we use *implausible* as [a stronger version of *improbable*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27720/plausible-vs-possible/27721#27721), meaning  "seemingly (but not absolutely) impossible", is there a word equivalently stronger than *probable*, e.g.  "seemingly (but not absolutely) certain"?

A diagram of the level of certainty that I ascribe to various words:

[image: impossible < implausible < improbable < possible < plausible < probable < ??? < certain]

You can say *almost certain*, *very likely*, *good bet*, *confident of*, etc, but is there a single word?

Conclusion: thanks for all the suggestions. Yes, I do understand that possibility, probability, and plausibility have different connotations regarding belief, information, truth, etc. I stand by my assertion that they each can be roughly measured on a 0-1 scale, even if the qualities being quantified are not exactly the same.

Comment: ***presumable***?

Comment: Not sure if you'll get a single work, but how about highly plausible?

Comment: I would say undeniable, as in the event's eventual occurrence is undeniable ?

Comment: *Believable* sounds a little stronger than *plausible*.

Comment: Implausible tells you that something *cannot happen*. The opposite of this is that something *can happen*. In your diagram, you interpret the opposite as something that *must happen*, which is awkward.

Comment: You are on to a good comparison, but your probability/plausibility scales are not corresponding intuitively.

Comment: `Likely`. By the way, the word you are likely looking for that means `one-word opposite` is `antonym`.

Comment: "Implausible tells you that something cannot happen"  totally incorrect.

Comment: note too that plausibility has no connection, at all, to probability.

Comment: indeed, im/possible has no connection at all to "certain".

Comment: See also [this](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=in-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we understand *implausible* to express "*I cannot believe it*", then it seems to me that its strong antonym should express "*I cannot doubt it*": so I propose **indubitable**.

A weaker contender might be *unquestionable*.

Comment: That's not what implausible means.

Comment: @curiousdannii, they may not be the words your dictionary of preference uses to gloss the term, but I think they do a fair job of conveying the subtext of real-world usage of a term which Cambridge can gloss as [difficult to believe](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/implausible) and which typically expresses a subjective opinion.

Answer (score 21):

The opposite of *implausible* is ***plausible***.
The word that belongs on the right-most side of your plausibility scale is ***convincing***.

---

I would tend to disagree about the relationship you have described between *implausible*/*plausible* and *improbable*/*probable*.

> *improbable*: "It is unlikely."
>   *probable*: "It is likely."
>   *implausible*: "I cannot imagine that there could be a case in which this would be true."
>   *plausible*: "I can imagine that there could be a case in which this could be true."

*(im)plausible* is based upon belief and opinion, whereas *(im)probable* is based upon statistical fact. The level of *plausibility* is based strictly upon the *depth of knowledge on the subject*, *gullibility*, and/or *faith* of person providing the opinion. To someone, a thing could be *implausible* while still being *certain* in reality.

> *convincing*: "I cannot imagine that there could be a case in which this would be false."

*Convincing* does not imply a *certain* outcome, but it does imply an individual's certainty by belief. Again, because you're trying to compare a subjective measure with a concrete measure, there will be oddities in definition. For example, a statistical probability that is *certain* is guaranteed to happen 100% of the time. Conversely, an individual can be *certain* about an outcome, yet still be proven incorrect.

---

An individual that is skeptical or closed-minded about a subject could have a plausibility scale measuring similar to this:

```
|---------------implausible---------------|--plausible--|
|---------improbable---------|---------probable---------|
```

An individual that is gullible or imaginative about a subject could have a plausibility scale measuring similar to this:

```
|-implausible-|----------------plausible----------------|
|---------improbable---------|---------probable---------|
```

A person's *perception* of a subject does not change the *probability*.

Comment: Using your formulation, I seek "I cannot imagine ... this would be false."

Comment: You are seeking a word referring to a statement made with conviction. You should still be careful about creating the diagram as you have; *(im)plausibility* is not related to *(im)probability* and therefore cannot be charted in that way.

Comment: Ian, this is a valid complaint about the formulation of the question, but does not include any attempt at an answer. If you propose to define *implausible* more concretely as "I cannot imagine that there could be a case in which this would be true," then the original question, which asks for a word at the other end of the spectrum, can be interpreted as looking for a single word that means, "I cannot imagine that there could be a case in which this would be false." Any ideas?

Comment: I gave it some more thought and I came to the conclusion that *convincing* is the answer.

Comment: I believe you have failed to read the answer to the end. Not only does it answer the question posed in the title of this page (as *plausible*), but it offers an answer to the question posted in the body of the page (as *convincing*).

Comment: I think you meant to write "The opposite of *implausible* is *convincing*" in the second part? Also perhaps it's better to make that the first part, and move your first part (which is comment about the question) to the end.

Comment: +1 Good adjustments; excellent answer! It **is** possible to compare plausibility and probability, but the comparison is limited logically, and skewed by the "judges" frame of reference. Reality is always related to perception is some fashion--even if it is convoluted ;-)

Answer (score 10):

*[Conclusive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/conclusive)* is at the most convincing end of the *argument* scale:

> adjective
>
> (Of evidence or argument) serving to prove a case; decisive or
>   convincing:

*[Plausible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/plausible)* is less convincing:

> adjective
>
> 1 (Of an argument or statement) seeming reasonable or probable:

*[Implausible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/implausible)* is still less convincing:

> adjective
>
> (Of an argument or statement) not seeming reasonable or probable;
>   failing to convince:

*[Inconceivable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inconceivable)* is still less convincing:

> adjective
>
> Not capable of being imagined or grasped mentally; unbelievable:

The corresponding *possibility* scale would be *certain*, *probable*, *improbable*, *impossible*.

OED

Comment: Scott introduces the overwhelming point here.  "plausible" (and implausible) refers **only to a statement or argument**, NOT to a happening, concept or event.

Comment: Kudos for being the ***first*** to focus this question toward an intelligent answer!

Answer (score 4):

## Uhhh...

the opposite of implausible is plausible.

Note that your diagram is totally wrong.  plausible and implausible are equally far from the center.

(If you feel they are not, you're just not familiar with the words.)

Note that the words certain, probability etc, on the diagram, have no connection to anything at all.  "plausible" (and implausible) **refers only to a statement or argument, NOT to a happening, concept or event**.

Answer (score 2):

You could go with the Mythbusters spectrum:

- Busted (= Implausible)
- Plausible
- Confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a broad, general purpose word that suggests very strong likelihood. Depending on the context I might consider words like: *undeniable,* *irrefutable,* *compelling,* *expected,* *probable,* or simply *likely*. (Yes, these latter two can just mean "more likely than not," but can have a stronger connotation depending on the context.)

Keep in mind, though, that "implausible" when used precisely has a meaning more like unbelievable than improbable - specifically, ["Not having the appearance of truth *(an implausable alibi)"*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/implausible). That is, if you tell me something I don't believe and I say it's improbable I'm probably questioning your factual knowledge, but if I say it's implausible I might be questioning your honesty.

Answer (score 0):

> Accepted.

What was once merely plausible, is now accepted as the truth.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with **certain** or **confirmed**, depending on circumstances. Something which is implausible is not believable. That which is plausible is believable but not necessarily true.

If someone has provided an explanation or alibi, and it is proven to be true, you would say that the alibi has been confirmed.

"His alibi is wildly implausible."

"His alibi is plausible, but we need to investigate it further."

"His alibi has been confirmed."

If you are making a prediction, you could say

"War with Japan is most implausible." (Although unlikely would probably be used here.)

"War with Japan is a plausible consequence of this policy, but is deemed unlikely."

"As a result of the attack on Pearl Harbor, war with Japan is certain."